# Stability analysis for PDE using von Neumann

Tags: inequality, partial-differential-equations, finite-differences

I need help understanding this stability analysis for the given finite difference approximation, I don't understand the middle part where if we assume $p^{2} >1 $ so $p>1$ how is this the same as $ p<-1$ , where did assumption come from? Also if $p<-1$ how does this make $ \left\lvert \xi _-\right\rvert>1$? can someone please look at the solution and explain? 
Thank you.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To ensure that $1-p^2\sin^2(\omega)<0$ for all $\omega$, it requires $p^2>1$, i.e. $p>1$ **OR** $p<-1$.

Addressing your first question, $p^2>1$ implies that ***either*** $p>1$ ***or*** $p<-1$, which makes sense, since in case of negative $p$ it can be written as $p = -1\!\cdot\! r,\ r\ge0$, and so 
$$
  p^2 = \left(-r\right)^2 = r^2  >1 \implies r >1 \implies p = -r <-1
$$

---

Also, since for the case $p^2>1$ we have

$$
  1-p^2\sin^2\omega<0 \qquad
  \text{and}\qquad 
  \left\lvert\xi_-\right\rvert = \big\lvert \,p\sin\omega -\sqrt{p^2\sin^2\omega - 1}\, \big\rvert
$$

The first condition $1-p^2\sin^2\omega<0$ means that the expression under root sign is non-negative.
If $p<-1$ and $-1\le\sin\omega\le1$ then the term $p\sin\omega$ can take values less than $-1$ (e.g. $\omega=\frac\pi2$) and so subtracting the (nonnegative) root term from $p\sin\omega$ will increase magnitude of the whole expression for certain values of $\omega$.

---

### Example

$$
  p=-2, \omega=\dfrac{\pi}{3} \Rightarrow p\sin\omega = -\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2}
  \Rightarrow \left\lvert\xi_-\right\rvert = \Big\lvert \,-\dfrac{\sqrt{3}}{2} - 
  \sqrt{\dfrac{9}{4} - 1}\, \Big\rvert = \Big\lvert \,\dfrac{-\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{5}}{2}\, \Big\rvert \approx 1.984.
$$

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I understand it a lot better, just wanted to ask when it’s say ‘for all values of omega is this between -pi and pi?

Comment: And also the part about if p>1,  $| \xi _+ | > 1$ for some omega? Thank you

Comment: @italy You are correct about $\omega$, I think. Although it could have been restricted previously in the book.
The part with $p>1\implies\left\lvert\xi_+\right\rvert>1$ for some $\omega$ follows exactly like the case in my answer, except instead of $\left\lvert\xi_-\right\rvert$ use formula for $\left\lvert\xi_+\right\rvert$ in the above derivations.